# Image Overlapping With Certain Width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to overlay several images on top of one another within an area set at a certain width. My problem is that when the combined width of these images exceed the area's width, some of the images are placed on the line below. I tried to fix this by using `left:-100px` to make the images overlap one another and to reduce the overall combined image's width, but the same problem still occurs.

I know a solution could be `boxC{top:-100px;}` but that means that there is an extra 100px generated in the window. As verification of this, you can minimize the vertical height of the browser and you will see that there is an invisible gap. http://postimage.org/image/5s0o82f81/

My question is how would I be able to overlay several images on top of one another within a certain width without having any images being placed on the line below.

What I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/xFkh6/2/

What I want: http://jsfiddle.net/d9xh8/2/ (notice that to achieve this I had to set `#wrapper{width:600px}`. I want to achieve this look by leaving it as `#wrapper{width:500px}` just like in the previous jsFiddle.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="boxA" class="box"></div>
    <div id="boxB" class="box"></div>
    <div id="boxC" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper { border:black 5px solid; width:500px; height:100px; margin:0 auto;}
.box { float:left; position:relative; top:0;}
#boxA {width:200px; height:100px; background:rgba(250,100,100,0.6); left:0px; }
#boxB {width:200px; height:100px; background:rgba(150,140,200,0.6); left:-50px;}
#boxC {width:200px; height:100px; background:rgba(100,250,250,0.6); left:-100px; top:-100px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of left and top use margin like this,

```
<style>
#wrapper { border:black 5px solid; width:500px; height:400px; margin:0 auto;}
#wrapper div { float:left;position:relative;}
#boxA {width:200px; height:100px; background:rgba(150,20,0,0.6); margin:0 0 0 0}
#boxB {width:200px; height:100px; background:rgba(150,40,100,0.6); margin:50px 0 0 -50px;}
#boxC {width:200px; height:100px; background:rgba(150,60,200,0.6); margin:100px 0 0 -50px;}  ​
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="boxA" class="box"></div>
    <div id="boxB" class="box"></div>
    <div id="boxC" class="box"></div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I've been looking for for days :)